# Assigning an absolute url to webresources.axd and Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, webresource.axd

Im working on a project where i am implementing a friendly url system using the url rewite module in ii7.

This is all good and works great.

My only issue is that webresources.axd and Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd both have relative paths. This causes lots of issues when the url is http://domain.com/some_page_name/

```
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=mJUUfJUeVsvUq18HY14aGg2&amp;t=634054669363345579" type="text/javascript"></script> 


<script src="/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=RadScriptManager1_TSM&amp;compress=1&amp;_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d3.5.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a1247b7d8-6b6c-419f-a45f-8ff264c90734%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2010.1.519.35%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3afcd44c12-f50d-4937-b05d-1aa46b5c5b3e%3a16e4e7cd%3aed16cbdc" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there anyway I can assign an absolute url to these resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thoughts of using [Telerik CDN](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radscriptmanager-cdn-support.html)for this purpose? Thus the resources should be served from static urls from the Telerik Amazon CloudFront storage.

Comment: Its not something that I had thought of. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again for the heads up on this. I have implemented the Telerik CDN now across the application now. Im running into the an issue with anything wrapped in the Telerik Ajax panel. I found this out by creating a test page with a few random telrik controls and standard controls using the CDN. Probably some switch that needs switching i will do a bit more digging.